# Problems with removing directories and files recursively

Tags: c++, recursion, directory

I am trying to remove all files and subdirectories from my command line interpreter. When the call is made to rmdir -s newFolder, i call a function removeAll which goes through all files and subfolders and deletes all the files.

For example if i want to delete the file newFolder, i delete all the files and go into newFolder1. I delete all the files in newFolder1 and go into newFolder2 and delete all the files. So now i am in newFolder 2 and newFolder, newFolder1, and newFolder2 are empty.

My question is how do i recurse back up and delete these 3 empty folders. I have debugged and worked on this for several hours and i am just not getting it. Thank you

This is the function that will successfully delete one empty folder, otherwise it calls removeAll.

```
void MyShell::rmdir () {
//Error Check
if(argc != 3) {
    printf("USAGE: rmdir [-s] <directory>\n");      
    return;
}
else if(stricmp(cwd, argv[2]) == 0){
    printf("Cannot remove the current working directory");
    return;
}
if(_rmdir(argv[2]) == 0)
    return;

removeAll(argv[2]);
```

}

The function removeAll successfully deletes all files in all subfolders

```
void removeAll(char *path)
{
    _chdir(path);

    _finddata_t data;

    intptr_t handle = _findfirst("*", &data);

    if(handle == -1)
    {
        return;
    }

    do 
    {
        if (strcmp(data.name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(data.name, "..") == 0)
        {
            continue;
        }

        remove(data.name);

        if(data.attrib & _A_SUBDIR)
        {
            removeAll(data.name);
        }

    } while(_findnext(handle, &data) != -1);

    _findclose(handle); 
}
```

My idea to recurse back up and delete all subfolders was to call a method after it breaks from the findnext loop

```
void removeDirectory(char *path)
{
    _finddata_t data;

    intptr_t handle = _findfirst("*", &data);

    if(handle == -1)
    {
        return;
    }

    do 
    {
        if (strcmp(data.name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(data.name, "..") == 0)
        {
            continue;
        }


        if(data.attrib & _A_SUBDIR)
        {
            if(_rmdir(data.name) == 0)
            {
                _chdir("..");
                removeDirectory(path);
            }

        }

    } while(_findnext(handle, &data) != -1);

    _findclose(handle); 
}
```

Comment: I recall my first recursive dir delete on DOS that found the '..' in the first entry and climbed up to delete everything. Fortunately it had another bug so my HD survived the first test.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of recursion is that you don't have to go "back up". Each iteration of the recursed routine should handle only its own level and then either call itself again or break out. It looks like you almost had it done. Try something like this for your RemoveAll routine:

```
void removeAll(char *path)
{
    _chdir(path);

    _finddata_t data;

    intptr_t handle = _findfirst("*", &data);

    if(handle == -1)
    {
        return;
    }

    while(_findnext(handle, &data) != -1)   // changed from do..while to just while
    {
        if (strcmp(data.name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(data.name, "..") == 0)
        {
            continue;
        }

        if(data.attrib & _A_SUBDIR)
        {
            removeAll(data.name);
            _rmdir(data.name);    // <- moved this to here
        }
        else
        {
            remove(data.name);
        }
    }

    _findclose(handle); 
}
```

Comment: I tried this code re arrangement you just wrote. Again, it correctly deletes all the files i need but not the folders i need to delete. I'm so confused

Comment: I think the problem is when it goes into the final subfolder that only has "." and ".." it just returns but i need it to recurse back up so to speak(although i understand recursion doesn't technically recurse back up, but deals at its own level) i cant figure this out, so frustrating!

Comment: So the `_rmdir(data.name)` call doesn't remove the empty directory? Next step would be to make sure the directories are really empty. Also try assigning the `_rmdir` return value to a variable and see if it's returning an error.

Comment: They are empty except for "." and ".." so after it compares those it says there are no more files or subdirectories(i.e. breaks out of the findnext) and finishes. so i go through new, new1, new2, new3 and return inside new3

Comment: I'm getting error printed twice when i set if(_rmdir(data.name) == -1) printf("Error")

Comment: Maybe i'm missing some logical step with the current working directory

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking that's the case. Maybe use `_getcwd` to store the current path before changing directories and then restore that path with another call to `_chdir` just before exiting removeAll().

Comment: It would really help me out if you could answer in source code. I've moved some things around but im still not getting it right. It now deletes the deepest folder but none of the empty ones above it i want deleted.

Comment: I finally got it!! Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that remove() will remove empty directories as well as files, you should just need to rearrange the code to this:

```
do 
{
    if (strcmp(data.name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(data.name, "..") == 0)
    {
        continue;
    }

    if(data.attrib & _A_SUBDIR)
    {
        removeAll(data.name);
    }

    remove(data.name);

} while(_findnext(handle, &data) != -1);
```

Basically, your recursive function should follow this pseudocode:

```
void deleteAll(path)
{
    for each file in path
    {
        if file is folder
        {
            // empty the folder
            deleteAll(file)
        }

        delete file // whether it is a now-empty folder or a file
    }
}
```

That way, when you encounter a folder, you immediately enter it and delete its contents and then return to the scope of its parent folder, where you can now delete it because it is empty.

Comment: remove does not delete folders, only files. i need _rmdir to delete an empty directory